# How Spanning Tree Protocol detects Loops

Tags: networking

For last few days I've been reading about Spanning Tree Protocol ,L2 protocol and understood how it prevents loop in network ,various steps in STP but one thing i wanted to know how STP actually detects the loops in network so that it can prevent it.Somewhere I read STP uses BPDU as probe and detects loops I mean how it happen is when switch send a BPDU with Destination Address as multicast and receive same BPDU again mean there is loop in network .

But is it how STP detects loops in network?

Answer (score 3):

For every bridge, it computes the least cost paths to the root bridge, and disable all other root paths by blocking the other ports. So obviously, any path including a loop wouldn't have the least cost, and would thus be discarded.

Comment: so, somehow, STP doesn't bother *detecting* loops: it just always prefer loopless paths because they're shorter...

Comment: Absolutely, that was my point :)